# Verify that 5 Textboxes have some content

Tags: c#, beginner, winforms

I'm new to C#.  I have created a form that has 5 text boxes and  this function checks to see if every text box has text in the box.  If not, then it displays a message box saying "Error (Add Text)".

I wanted to see if there was a way to simplify this, or if this is the best way of completing this task :)

```
    private bool ValidInput()
    {
        bool isValid = true;
        //Check Title
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(titleText.Text))
        {
            //Message Box Pass Through Title
            MB("The Title can't be blank!", "Error!", MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            titleText.Focus();
            isValid = false;
        }
        //Check Artist
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(artistText.Text))
        {
            //Message Box Pass Through Artist
            MB("The Artist can't be blank!", "Error!", MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            artistText.Focus();
            isValid = false;
        }
        //Check Genre
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(genreText.Text))
        {
            //Message Box Pass Through Genre
            MB("The Genre can't be blank!", "Error!", MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            genreText.Focus();
            isValid = false;
        }
        //Check Year
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(yearText.Text))
        {
            //Message Box Pass Through Year
            MB("The Year can't be blank!", "Error!", MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            yearText.Focus();
            isValid = false;
        }
        //Check URL
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(urlText.Text))
        {
            //Message Box Pass Through URl
            MB("The URL can't be blank!", "Error!", MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            urlText.Focus();
            isValid = false;
        }
        return isValid;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private bool ValidInput()
{
     bool isValid = true;
     List<string[]> controlList = new List<string[]>(); //Control name, then display name.

     controlList.Add(new[] { "titleText", "Title"});
     controlList.Add(new[] { "artistText", "Artist" });
     controlList.Add(new[] { "genreText", "Genre" });
     controlList.Add(new[] { "yearText", "Year" });
     controlList.Add(new[] { "urlText", "URL" });

     for (int i = 0; i < controlList.Count; i++)
     {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Controls[controlList[i][0]].Text))
         {
            MB("The " + controlList[i][1] + " can't be blank!", "Error!", MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            this.Controls[controlList[i][0]].Focus();
            isValid = false;
            break;
         }
     }
     return isValid;
}
```

Comment: You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].

Comment: This one works amazingly! Because it allows for more then just TextBox's so if I change one of the box's to a ComboBox it still works :D Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you can use `Dictionary` to store the `TextBox`s and their representive name, then just iterate over them, something like this :

```
private bool ValidInput()
{
    Dictionary<string, TextBox> textBoxes = new Dictionary<string, TextBox>
    {
        { "Title", titleText },
        { "Artist", artistText },
        { "Genre", genreText },
        { "Year" , yearText},
        { "URL", urlText }
    };

    foreach(var item in textBoxes)
    {
        var name = item.Key;
        var textbox = item.Value;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))
        {
            MB($"The {name} can't be blank!", "Error!", MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            textbox.Focus();
            return false;
        }
    }


    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Each `Control` does have a property called [`Tag`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tag). This can contain/hold any kind of information since its type is `object`.

1. Assign the `Title`, ... ,`Url` values to the corresponding TextBox's `Tag`:

```
private readonly TextBox[] textBoxes = new [] { titleText, ... , urlText };
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   titleText.Tag = "Title";
   ...
   urlText.Tag = "URL";
}
```

2. Rewrite your `ValidInput` like this:

```
var textbox = textBoxes.FirstOrDefault(tb => string.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text));
if (textbox == null) return true;

MB($"The {textbox.Tag} can't be blank!", "Error!", MessageBoxIcon.Error);
textbox.Focus();
return false;
```

Answer (score 2):

.net already provides a mechanism to validate `TextBox`es and other controls. It's called the [Validating event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.validating?view=windowsdesktop-6.0). This works in combination with the [ErrorProvider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) that allows you to easly show an error message.

By wiring and handling this event you don't need any dictionaries, loops, arrays and alike.